# Disable Time in Angular Bootsrap DateTime Picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating Project using angularjs.I am using DatetimePicker in my project.The Link is

https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

In One place I want to show only date not the time. But I dont know how can i disable the time.

Here is code:

```
$scope.config = {
  datetimePicker: {
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  }
};
```

In HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" style="right: -15px; top: 4px;">
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="assCustmoers.date"
data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown1' }"></datetimepicker>
</ul>
```

Comment: could you replicate the same on plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: @angular is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.embeddedDate"
        data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'day', minView:'day' }" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the input as follows:
Add this module as a dependency to your application module:

`var myAppModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.dateTimeInput']);`

and apply the directive to your form elements:

`<datetimepicker data-date-time-input="DD/MM/YYYY" data-ng-model="assCustmoers.date"
data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown1' }"></datetimepicker>`

you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-date-time-input).